# Yii2 - добавление в бд MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

Не могу понять, что не так.
Есть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно в неё через форму добавлять новые записи.
Сама форма:

```
<?php $model = new RegistrationForm(); ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => '?r=site/save',
        'method' => 'post',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'surname') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'position') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'login') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Закончить регистрацию', ['id' => 'send']);?>
<?php ActiveForm::end()?>
```

Контроллер, где делаю добавление:

```
   public function actionSave()
    {
        $model = new RegistrationForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->name = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["name"];
            $model->surname = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["surname"];
            $model->position = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["position"];
            $model->login = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["login"];
            $model->password = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["password"];
            $model->save();

        } else {
            echo "Ошибка";
        }

    }
```

Модель:

```
class RegistrationForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $position;
    public $login;
    public $password;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name', 'surname', 'position', 'login','password'], 'required'],

            [ ['password'],'string','min'=>6],
    ];

    }

    public static function tableName(){
return "user";
    }
}
```

При заполнении полей и нажатии на кнопку таблица заполняется пустыми полями. При этом, если посмотреть $model через var_dump, то видно, что модель заполнена введёнными данными.
Не могу понять, почему тогда сохраняются пустые поля. Подскажите варианты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите из модели строки

```
public $name;
public $surname;
public $position;
public $login;
public $password;
```

и будет Вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо. При работе с БД для формы не нужно создавать атрибуты? Насколько я знаю, если создаётся форма, то для неё в модели нужно указывать атрибуты

Comment: Если создаёте какие то поля которых нет в таблице БД, но они нужны Вам при работе, то создаёте их (`public $value;`).

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь всё понятно

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Уберите из действия **actionSave()** следующие строки.

```
        $model->name = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["name"];
        $model->surname = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["surname"];
        $model->position = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["position"];
        $model->login = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["login"];
        $model->password = $_POST["RegistrationForm"]["password"];
```

они тут явно лишние.
Не создавайте экземпляр модели в представлении, делайте это в контроллере.
Уберите из представления **$model = new RegistrationForm();** и перепишите действие в контроллере так, как показано ниже. Для **redirect** подставьте нужный путь, а для **render** нужный файл представления.

```
public function actionSave(){
   $model = new RegistrationForm;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Если Вам надо получить данные из POST массива, то в yii2 есть встроенный метод.

```
Yii::$app->request->post();
```

Так как Вы это делаете - неверно.

Comment: Спасибо. Учусь пока, не всё знаю и понимаю)

Comment: Буду очень признателен, если вы объясните как вся эта магия работает. Ибо я делал так, как мне понятно)

Comment: Читайте больше документации, например эту https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru и ещё куча есть хороших ресурсов.

Comment: ну не тут объяснять, если хотите, то можно позже созвониться в skype

Comment: Созвониться не смогу, но если вам не лень будет писать, то вот мой скайп: arakul881.